# Appending JSON data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to append a `span` here using JSON data. But the problem is that I want to append this `span` with some class named "xyz". Is it possible if yes, how ?

```
function refresh() {
    var $table = $("table#mytable");

    $.getJSON("//127.0.0.1:8001/get_latest_verification", function (obj) {

        $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
            var rows = "";

            rows = rows + "<tr>" + "<td>" + value.asset_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.scan_time + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.credential + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<span>" + value.status + "</span>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.operator + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.auth_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.emp_id + "</td>" + "</tr>";

            $table.prepend(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to append <span> with a class, somthing like 
span should be appended with a certain class....

Comment: Where do you want to append it to? a table row?

Comment: yea to a table row, same as u can see in code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way: you are doing nothing more than prepending html inside of a table element.  jQuery will append the exact HTML string you create, you just need to make sure you are creating a good HTML string in the first place.  Here is the sane way to build HTML strings in Javascript, note the use of single quotes and backslashes:

```
var htmlstring = '<tr>\
    <td>' + value.someValue + '</td>\
    <td>' + value.someOtherValue + '</td>\
    <td><span class="xyz">' + value.whatever + '</span></td>\
</tr>';
```

If you learn to build HTML strings this way, you may end up discovering that your HTML isn't the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class name, the span you already have there

```
+"<td>"+"<span class='xyz'>" + value.status +"</span>" +"</td>"
```

Comment: Ofcourse that is working. There is not much to do wrong here.Maybe the code is failing elsewhere. Please add `console.log(rows);` before you prepend it to th table. Then have a look if it looks correctly in the console. Also what is not working? Do you even successfully can add the rows to the table without the class?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add it just like this?

```
rows=rows+"<tr>"+"<td>" +value.asset_code+"</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.scan_time + "</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.credential + "</td>"
                          +"<td>"+"<span>" + value.status +"</span>" +"</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.operator + "</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.location + "</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.auth_code + "</td>"
                          +"<td>" + value.emp_id + "</td>"
                          +"<span class=\"xyz\">SPAN TEXT</span>"
                          +"</tr>";
```